# Facebook Live video suddenly stop working, even permission are approved from facebook team?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my c# based desktop app, I am live streaming to Facebook. The App is submitted to Facebook and they approved the permission.

Things were working quite fine but suddenly yesterday I check the app and the app is not working anymore. It's work fine if the user is tester, developer or admin of the app.

The error I see in return JSON response is this

"(#10) To use live-video-API on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review"

I am not sure what is going wrong. If Facebook has approved the permission then why it's making error 10. I have searched a lot of docs on facebook developer site but couldn't find any details that can help on this issue.

Comment: You need not only get the permissions reviewed, but the feature “Live Video API” itself as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-LIVE_VIDEOS

Comment: any info or updates?